# Change vertical alignment into horizontal for bootstrap checkboxes

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I want to make my `checkbox` align horizontally. By default they're `vertical` in `bootstrap`.

What I need is to align them horizontally.

`CSS`:

```
.checkboxinsameline{
    display:inline;
}
```

`HTML`:

```
               <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-2">Ekstra Tanım Tipi</label>
                    <div class="col-md-3">

                            <div ng-repeat="item in DefinitionTypes">
                                <label class="checkboxinsameline">
                                    <input  type="checkbox" name="item.value" ng-click="DefinitionTypesChecked(item.id)"> {{item.value}}
                                </label>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div><br />
```

Please help.

Comment: There is only one checkbox in your sample code.

Comment: By reading the [doc](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#inline-checkboxes-and-radios)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply `checkboxinsameline` class to div intead of lable. Like below

```
<div class="checkboxinsameline" ng-repeat="item in DefinitionTypes">
     <label>
            <input  type="checkbox" name="item.value" ng-click="DefinitionTypesChecked(item.id)"> {{item.value}}
     </label>
</div>
```

I think this should solve your problem.If not provide fiddle or plunker demonstrating your problem.